# JavaScript（TypeScript）でPromise.allの戻り値を変数に格納出来ない。

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, next.js

Next.jsでブログを作成しています。下記のコードはGitHubリポジトリの内容を取得して、それを加工して `datas` に格納したいのですが、上手く行きません。
`console.log(datas)` しても `undefined`と表示されます。詳しい方見ていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```
const datas = await (async (zennArticles) => {
    if (zennArticles) {
      await Promise.all(zennArticles.map(async (article: Article) => {
        const data = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/wimpykid719/zenn-content/contents/articles/" + article.name, {
          headers: {"Authorization": "token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
        })
          .then(res => {
              return res.json();
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
        const buffer = Buffer.from(data.content, 'base64');
        const fileContents = buffer.toString("utf-8");
        const matterResult = matter(fileContents)
        const processedContent = await remark()
          .use(html)
          .process(matterResult.content)
        const contentHtml = processedContent.toString()
        return {
          id: article.name,
          ...(matterResult.data as { title: string; emoji: string; type: string; topics: string[]; published: boolean }),
          content: contentHtml,
        }
      }));
    }
  })(zennArticles);
  console.log(datas)

//実行結果
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promiseに関する質問かと思いますので、本質的でない remarkjs(?) などの処理を除外して考えると以下の様になるかと思います。

```
type Article = {
  name: string
  sha: string
  size: number
  url: string
  html_url: string
  git_url: string
  download_url: string
  type: string
};

type Content = {
  name: string
  path: string
  sha: string
  size: number
  url: string
  html_url: string
  git_url: string
  download_url: string
  type: string
  content: string
  encoding: string
};
```

```
let data: ReadonlyArray<Record<string, unknown>> = [];
const setData = (values: ReadonlyArray<Record<string, unknown>>) => { data = values; }

const getArticles = async (): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Article>> =>
  fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/wimpykid719/zenn-content/contents/articles/")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return [];
    });

const getContents = async (zennArticles: ReadonlyArray<Article>): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Content>> => {
    if (zennArticles.length > 0) {
      return Promise.all(
        zennArticles
        .map(async (article: Article) => {
          return fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/wimpykid719/zenn-content/contents/articles/${article.name}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
      })).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return [];
      });
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

const getData = async (): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Record<string, unknown>>> => {
  const articles = await getArticles();
  const contents = await getContents(articles);

  // FIXME: remarkjs で　content を HTML に変換したりなどする。
  //        関数などを定義して呼び出してもよい。
  // const data = await parseContents(contents);
  // return data;

  console.log(contents);

  return contents;
}

getData().then(setData);
```

[上記コードのTypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ih1amqQxoAqunLckmTLoFQP4QHir44JhkHfNBqrAPWAAGOp6hQhrGmaFpWjaQr2o6zquu6nren6QYhlEEZxhEsZ9EuRroamAAk2BESmpoJBAPiMVWg66dmrC5vmhbFmWFY4jprY+OZNp1hqjbNtRUDtp23ZwL2cDTrpQ60XAY4vAOg5WQFBA+FAECoKKVG6VBvnjsFVIsNSuC0lM9K-P8K7sgRPL8rB17ijC97wjKSIoocJxnJc1x3PclEtilUCqTurI2MQhhQGlZHUDyAUNVJCYtW1qXzrJETdU1v7TiwhpQAAYgAkgAGgAsgAolQDo4XA5xllAgDmDIAAAz9VAgBJDFAAASAAqy0ADJQIA1gyAJCagDbxoA6gyAPoMgBRDIAVgyAJYMgCaDIA0QyAEAM036l5UCAEWpgAOpn9J2AFnagCV-q9gBmDIAPiqAM4MgBfiqjgBBDIAEQyACIMoMEDNDUWBljWte1qRwKKT5LgC-XUJ5UAzTFY4U8SAQsM5ED-lYjBM6NCZTd5I6xczARJWlfzEjy+m5qK6XEtOQA)で動作を確認してみてください。

※ 極力コードが短くなるように一部変更しています
※ `Record<string, unknown>` は `{}` と同義です。([`typescript-eslint#ban-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md))
※ `ReadonlyArray<>` は、この型にしておくと、その配列を直接変更するようなメソッド呼び出しができなくなります。

---

**質問に書かれているコードについて**

- catchで値を返すとそれ以降の　`then()` でその値が返ります

  - 今回は、error loggingだけしておいて、とりあえず空配列などを返しておけばよいと思います
- `async`関数では必ず「値」か「Promise」を返しましょう

  - 値を返した場合、`Promise.resolve()`でその値を返した扱いになります
  - 「`Promise.all()`が返すPromise」や「`zennArticles`がfalsyの場合」などで一切returnをしていないので、このasync関数は `(zennArticles: Array<Article>) => Promise<void>`になっています

    - なので、このasync関数の `then()` の戻り値は必ず `undefined` になるかと思います
  - 慣れないうちは、async関数の戻り値の型を書いておくことをおすすめします

    - その型の戻り値を返していない場合に、コンパイルが通らなくなります
- 回答のように`async`関数を単一機能ごとに分けて定義すれば、動作確認や問題の切り分けが楽になりそうな気がします
- `Promise.all()`は1つでも失敗すると、全体が失敗します

  - 個別のエラー処理が不要であれば、`Promise.all()`の後で`catch()`すればいいかと思います

```js
Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve(0),
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.reject(new Error("Error in 2")),
  Promise.resolve(3),
  Promise.resolve(4)
])
  .then(numbers => { console.log(numbers); })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  });
```

---

**余談**

`Promise.all()`でエラーが起きたものだけ除外したい場合、各`Promise`でArrayを返して型を`T[][]`にしておき、取得するときに`Array.prototype.flat()`で`T[]`に変換してしまう方法などもあります。

```js
const promises = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(n => {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    // 値を配列に包んで返す
    return Promise.resolve([n]);
  } else {
    // エラーが起きたものは空配列を返すようにしておく
    // -> 2次元配列を .flat() した時に消える
    return Promise.reject(new Error(`Error in ${n}`))
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
        return [];
      });
  }
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(numbersNestedArray => numbersNestedArray.flat())
  .then(numbers => { console.log(numbers); });
```

Comment: コードの提供までありがとうございます。 `return await Promise.all(zennArticles.map(async (article: Article) => {` とする事で目的とする動作は出来たのですが、やはりコードを分けて行った方が良いという事でしょうか？

Comment: 「何故分けるべきか」に対して疑問を持っている状態で分けても適切に処理を分けられませんし、分けること自体が目的になってしまうので、今はそのままでも良いかもしれません。回答に書いた以外の視点では、例えば今のコードのままcontentをremarkjsで変換する処理に対してテストコードを書こうとすると、必ずfetchが行われる(ネットワークアクセスが発生する)為、テストが書きづらい(保守性が低い)コードにはなっています。

Comment: そうですね。テストコードをまだ書いた事がないので、詳しくは分からないですが、毎回fetchが行われるのは煩わしいです。